# git remote repository from local repo with all files from local repo

Tags: git, version-control

I am a noob to git.
as I need to collaborate on my source code with another dev.
I am trying to create a remote repo in a fileshare on a remote server. something like \Xserver\fileshares\gitsharedrepo.git

I have a latest git repo at my local machine.
How can i use git to 
1. create remote git repo
2. setup a connection to remote repo
3. make sure remote repo has all the source code.
4. dont care about the history on remote repo as of yet. 
5. once connection between local and remote repo exists, how can i make changes at local repo, add, commit to local repo and make sure thoese changes are send to the remote repo as well.
(including, change to file, add/dele file etc).
6. how can i create a new local copy in some other folder on my local machine from remote repo and have all the source code in new local copy.

PS: cannot use github to such tools due to network restriction. this is a closed network boundary, i believe i cannot even have privilege for SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks. 
After doing some search I found out that bare repo contains file in pack objects and not as regular files with extension. 
so i pushed my local repo to remote one and then 
using remote repo i created another local repository on second machine.
now two servers have connection to same remote repo.